# Estimating eigenvalues of second order linear ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Suppose an ODE is given by a linear operator $L$ where
$$L = P(x)\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + Q(x) \frac{d}{dx}$$
and we would like to find the eigenvalues of this operator so that
$$Ly = \lambda y.$$
I am interested in theorems that either estimate $\lambda$ or can give a bound for $\lambda$. The only result I am aware of is when the ODE is a Sturm-Liouville problem, for which we can use the Rayleigh quotient. I'm not sure much can be said in general. What if we put more conditions on $P$ and $Q$ beyond them just being continuous, for example that they're trigonometric, polynomials, or periodic? Is the only way to determine $\lambda$ through direct computation?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $P(x)>0$ and divide by it to see that the equation is equivalent to

$$y'' + \frac{Q}{P}y' = \lambda \frac{1}{P}y$$
Next, define $\mu = \exp\left({\int\dfrac{Q}{P}dx }\right)>0$. If we multiply through by $\mu$ and use the fact that $$(\mu y')' = \mu y'' + \frac{Q}{P}\mu y'$$
then the equation reduces to

$$(\mu y')' = \lambda \frac{\mu}{P}y$$
which is a Sturm Liouville equation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am looking for a more concrete way to get a bound on the eigenvalues.